# Как узнать рing сервера python

Tags: python, ping

как получить время задержки с серверу, то есть не состояние сервера, online или offline, а именно **число задержки в ms**. И есть ли метод, котрый будет выполнять это без зависимости к операционной системы?

Пример точно что мне нужно:

```
>>>ping("google.com")
36ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте библиотеку ping3 https://github.com/kyan001/ping3

```
pip install ping3
```

Команда ping возвращает задержку в секундах

```
from ping3 import ping

print(ping('example.com'))  #Возвращает задержку в секундах
```

Для возврата значения в ms:

```
ping('example.com', unit='ms')
```